# cross hair on chart in c#

Tags: c#, charts

I created a cross hair or chart and I and its working, now I want to change the position of y-axis form left to right (I fixed it form chart 
properties-> series(collection)->y-axis type change primary to secondary )then its show only x-axis line, i want also y-asix, how can I fix it, my code is below..

```
//for X axis line 
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineWidth = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineColor = Color.Red;
            //chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;

            //for Y axis line 
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineWidth = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;


            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Interval = 0;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);

            label2.Text = "pixel of X=" + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X).ToString();
            label3.Text = "pixel of X2=" + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y).ToString();
```

Comment: Where did you put  this code ? Is it in a Paint method, as necessary by [MSDN on PixelPositionToValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.pixelpositiontovalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)                              { all code here}

Comment: How do you change to y-axes? After doing this: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;}`  your code still runs just fine.

Comment: its not working. i replace  this code in my code, x line display but y line is not displaying

Comment: That is strange. As I wrote it works just fine here. What is your chart type? Could you post a link to an image of the chart..?

Comment: There are many free file/image upload services. Try http://imgur.com/ or http://www.file-upload.net/ .They will let you upload the image and give you the url. Then you can post the it in your answer. Also: you should not post your mail address here. Please delete the comment, ok?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ufI0RMw

Comment: I have looked at the chart and am still amazed. I think there must be something else going on somewhere in your code but can't imaging what. So to be sure: When you have the (normal) Y-Axis to the left the horizontal cursor line shows but when you switch to Y2-Axis it doesn't?? Do you add any scaling to the Y2-Axis?

Comment: when i change the property of chart series form primary to secondary then its not working, can you please give me your email address so that i can send you my project demo

Comment: The best place to upload a project for inspection would be GitHub.com

Answer (score 1):

Use `AxisY2` instead:

```
        label2.Text = "Pixel of X Position = " + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X).ToString("0.00");
        label3.Text = "Pixel of Y Position = " + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y).ToString("0.00");
```

[image]

Comment: You can't blindly "replace code".... You have to understand what I'm telling you..... primary axis = use `AxisY`, secondary axis = use `AxisY2`